# How can I add multiple form fields (at once) with an 'add new fields' button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, custom-fields

See http://jsfiddle.net/jFzhC/ for the button I'm looking for.  Although, this only allows for one input field to be added at a time.

How can I display 3 fields, horizontally aligned, where the 'add new fields' button creates 3 additional new fields under the original 3 and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clone a template and save yourself a lot of code at the same time:

http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/bPhBG/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/cADRY/1/

You can simplify your code A LOT!

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to save the most recent edit, it's been updated. Thanks